# Finding the average temperature over a certain amount of time

Tags: calculus

[image: Image attached]

I'm assuming you use some time of equation such as the Mean Value Theorem of Integrals to find the average here, but the equation is not represented in the form of an integral, so I'm not entirely sure how to begin.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, by just using definition of average

$T_{avg}=\frac{1}{30}\int_0^{30} { T(t) dt }$

Answer (score 0):

First of all that formula is wrong, because after few minutes a coffee is always cold, and here after 30 minutes a cup of coffe is at **61°C**!!!

**I mean this is a killer coffee!!!** *(normal people over 49°C get permanent injuries!)*

However, here we have 2 solutions very close:  *(use http://asciimath.org/ to see formulas)*

math average:
`T_0 = 95°C
T_30 = 61.16°C
T_m_av = (95+61.16) / 2 = 78.08 °C`

Integral average:

```
T_i_av = 1/30 int_0^30 (20 + 75e^(-t/50)) dt = 76.40 °C
```

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\frac1t\int_0^t e^{-t/\tau}dt=\frac\tau t(1-e^{-t/\tau}).$$

Then with the initial temperature difference $\Delta_0=T_0-T_\infty$ and the difference at time $t,$$$\Delta_t=T_t-T_\infty=(T_0-T_\infty)e^{-t/\tau}=\Delta_0e^{-t/\tau},$$ the average is given by

$$\overline\Delta=\Delta_0\frac\tau t(1-e^{-t/\tau})=\Delta_0\frac\tau t-\Delta_t.$$